# Enable IE6 to run JavaScript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6

How do I enable IE6 to run JavaScript?
Where in the settings do I set this option?

Comment: He tried but his javascript is disabled!

Answer (score 1):

> Tools > Internet Options > Security

Then select the Internet zone if it's not already selected.

Click **Custom Level...**

Scroll down to the section node labelled, **Scripting**.

On the Active Scripting branch, select **Enable**.

You will then see this prompt:

> Are you sure you want to change the security settings for this zone?

Click **Yes** and then click **OK**.

Reload the page or restart IE6 and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have IE6 anymore, but in IE8 (which you should upgrade to), it is in Tools/Internet Options/Advanced.  Maybe it's in the same place in IE6.